# Dynamic controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to do this to load a controller dynamically:

```
<div ng-controller="{{someVar}}"><!-- stuff --></div>
```

but I get an error because it tries to load a controller literally named {{someVar}}

Is there a way to dynamically load a controller

Comment: You'd need a controller to determine the right controller. Why?

Answer (score 0):

you can create objects dynamically, using below code

```
Class controllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"MyViewController") ;
id object = [[controllerClass alloc] init] ;
[object method_name] ;
```